# How to update Bios of a Lenovo Ideapad

Tags: upgrade, bios, ideapad

I've recently purchased an Ideapad 530S-14ARR. I would like to update the Bios to this device but the bios update package is only available for Windows. What options do I have to update it?

Currently using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: It is not officially supported via [fwupd](https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist). And on Arch Wiki only [one](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lenovo_IdeaPad_Z510#BIOS) IdeaPad article mentions BIOS updates, and even then it is only to admit that it can be done on Windows only.

Someone else might still find resources I didn't look for. Also I have done some kind of USB thumbdrive-based BIOS updates on a Lenovo Thinkpad X1 Carbon 6th gen.

Comment: @Karel Ahoj, the issue is not the same. The one you referenced was for a specfic model (some toshiba model). They are not the same as they may both have different methods.